# Why is this UIAlertView's Position not changing?

Tags: ios, uialertview, cgrect, uialertviewdelegate

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Blah"
                                                           message:nil
                                                          delegate:nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Enter", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
alert.delegate = self;
[alert show];

alert.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,100);
```

I've tried adding an AffineTransform as well. But it just doesn't change. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Any word on this? Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is just Apple trying to get everyone to move to UIAlertControllers. `UIAlertController` moves automatically. So that would be my suggestion to anyone here.